# Loop through values of a list inside of a dictionary that's inside another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

I am trying to make a sort of quiz game to memorise cocktail specs.
I created a dictionary called "cocktails" and inside of it there are keys as cocktail names (Negroni, Aperol Spritz) and as value there is another dictionary for each cocktail with "spirits" and "dose" keys with lists of values. I coded this and it works but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it since I want to add lots more cocktails.
I am looking for a loop that "loops" through every value inside of the list when the answer is correct instead of me having to type in manually the value everytime with the if/ else statements.

Basically I want to loop through those two automatically if the answer is correct:

`cocktails["negroni"]["spirits"][0]` and
`cocktails["negroni"]["ml"][0]`

so the [0] should become [1](https://github.com/Foghos/my-projects/blob/main/nested%20dictionary%20ex.py) and then [2] in both of the lines every time the loop continues.
I hope I explained it clearly. Ps: I'm very new to programming :)

This is the code I'm working with:
[code](https://github.com/Foghos/my-projects/blob/main/nested%20dictionary%20ex.py)

```
cocktails = {
    "negroni": {
       "spirits": ["gin", "vermouth", "campari"],
       "ml": [25, 25, 25],
    },
    "aperol_spritz": {
        "spirits": ["aperol", "prosecco", "soda"],
        "ml": [50, 50, "top"]
    }
}
cocktail = "Negroni"
print(cocktail)
stop_quiz = True
while stop_quiz:
    guess = int(input(cocktails["negroni"]["spirits"][0] + ": "))
    if guess != cocktails["negroni"]["ml"][0]:
        continue
    else:
        guess = int(input(cocktails["negroni"]["spirits"][1] + ": "))
        if guess != cocktails["negroni"]["ml"][1]:
            continue
        else:
            guess = int(input(cocktails["negroni"]["spirits"][2] + ": "))
            if guess != cocktails["negroni"]["ml"][2]:
                continue
            else:
                print("You know how to make a " + cocktail + "!")
                answer = input("Do you want to play again? ")
                if answer == "yes":
                    continue
                elif answer == "no":
                    print("See you soon!")
                    stop_quiz = False
```

Comment: I would advice to take a look at [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).  When using classes you can make a function to verify the input per attribute of the class (creating a for loop over all of the attributes, and if all are right return `True`, otherwise `False`.

Comment: thank you, I haven't got to classes yet :) I will update the project in the future then!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to get what you want, I would advice to take a look at classes to get a more object oriented approach. With that said, let's do it without classes!

Note: I also made some suggestions to your code to make it slightly simpler and adhere to the variable naming.

```
cocktails = {
    "negroni": {
        "spirits": ["gin", "vermouth", "campari"],
        "ml": [25, 25, 25],
    },
    "aperol_spritz": {
        "spirits": ["aperol", "prosecco", "soda"],
        "ml": [50, 50, "top"]
    }
}
```

Game:

```
cocktail = 'negroni'
print(cocktail)

stop_quiz = True
while stop_quiz:

    for spirit, amount in zip(cocktails[cocktail]['spirits'], cocktails[cocktail]['ml']):
        guess = int(input(f"{spirit}: "))
        while guess != amount:
            print("You are wrong :( , try again!")
            guess = int(input(f"{spirit}: "))

    print("You know how to make a " + cocktail + "!")
    answer = input("Do you want to play again? ")
    if answer == "yes":
        continue
    elif answer == "no":
        print("See you soon!")
        stop_quiz = False
```

### Explanation

We make use of the following 2 things:

1. Pythons built in [zip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip)
2. A kind of `do while` loop.

The `zip` iterator creates a loop that contains your spirit and answer:

```
for spirit, amount in zip(cocktails[cocktail]['spirits'], cocktails[cocktail]['ml']):
```

Now you can iterate over all the different spirits, and you already have the right answers to compare with.

In Python there is no such thing as a `do while` loop by default. But we can simulate the behavior of asking something until we get what we want. We first ask for an input amount, and if this is not what we want we ask again (and again ...).

```
guess = int(input(f"{spirit}: "))
while guess != amount:
    print("You are wrong :( , try again!")
    guess = int(input(f"{spirit}: "))
```

When the player successfully guesses all the spirits amounts you will get the end message and prompted to play again.

### Improvements

Now there are a few things that could be changed to improve the code:

- the value `stop_quiz` is `True`, but it makes more sense to make it `False`, and check the opposite condition in the `while` loop. Or you can change the name to for example `running`.
- At the end you prompt a `yes` and `no` question, but you continue the `yes` question if this is `True`. So why check for it at all? Also there is no else statement, so you really only have to check for the `no` value.

```
cocktail = 'negroni'  # same as list(cocktails)[0]
print(cocktail)

running = True
while running:

    for spirit, amount in zip(cocktails[cocktail]['spirits'], cocktails[cocktail]['ml']):
        guess = int(input(f"{spirit}: "))
        while guess != amount:
            print("You are wrong :( , try again!")
            guess = int(input(f"{spirit}: "))

    print("You know how to make a " + cocktail + "!")
    answer = input("Do you want to play again? ")

    if answer == 'no':
        print("See you soon!")
        running = False
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was really helpful!